# (count($list) for 1 or 2 items

Tags: php, joomla

The part where the script tells that if there are 1 or 2 script posts double. I only want ( if there are 1 or 2 articles) it only shows 1 or 2 articles

```
<?php
    defined('_JEXEC') or die;
    $count = 0;
    if (count($list)%3!=0) {
        $list = array_merge($list, array_slice($list, 0, 3-count($list)%3));
    }
    if (count($list)%2!=0) {
        $list = array_merge($list, array_slice($list, 0, 2-count($list)%2));
    }
    if (count($list)%1!=0) {
        $list = array_merge($list, array_slice($list, 0, 1-count($list)%1));
    }
?>

<?php JLoader::register('fieldattach', 'components/com_fieldsattach/helpers/fieldattach.php'); ?>

<div id="slides">
    <div class="slides_container">

        <div class='slide'>
            <?php foreach ($list as $item) :
                if (($count>0) and ($count%3==0)): ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slide">
                <?php endif; ?>

                <li class="categories">
                    <a href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>">
                        <?php echo fieldattach::getImg($item->id, 6); ?>
                        <h4><?php echo $item->title; ?></h4>
                    </a>
                </li>

            <?php $count++; endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey welcome to stackoverflow. So what does it do at the moment when you run it?

Comment: FYI, any integer % 1 = 0. I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish with the 3 modulo ifs, but the last one will never happen.

Comment: I'll try to explain it differently; The first part works perfect, but when there are 1 or 2 $items i want the script to do nothing but post the $item